# Resizing frames with width constraints

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have simple form `TForm1` with 2 panels. First with `Align := alLeft` and second with `Align := alClient` and empty frame `TFrame1`. When i add following procedures to the form, everything works without problems.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lFrame1, lFrame2 : TFrame1;
begin
  lFrame1 := TFrame1.Create(nil);
  lFrame1.Parent := pnl1;
  lFrame1.Align  := alClient;
  lFrame2 := TFrame1.Create(nil);
  lFrame2.Parent := pnl2;
  lFrame2.Align  := alClient;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pnl1.Width := ClientWidth div 2;
end;
```

[image]

But when I set `Constrains` for `TFrame1`, for example `TFrame1.Contraints.MinWidth := 100` and maximize and restore the form, then the form won't return to its previous state. Regardless of frame size, form size or constrains values, it always ends the same way. In my case default form has 300 width and after maximize and restore it ends with 1062. However without `Constraints` or `FormResize` it works. Can someone explain this strange behavior?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify, *...and maximize and restore the form, then the form won't return to its previous state...* What was the previous state and what did it actually return to? We can't or won't calculate pixels from your images.

Comment: What is the designed size of `TFrame1`?

Comment: Ok, I managed to replicate the problem. It occurs if you assigned the constraint of the frame in the unit where the frame is designed. It does not occur if you assign the constraint in the host form using the references `lFrame1` and `lFrame2`.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg That's exactly the problem. I have frame which I use often in connection with spitters. One way was to set constraints for panels every time I use the frame, but I still wonder, why it behaves like this.

Comment: This seems to be a bug and I think you should report it to [Embarcadero Quality portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com). As a workaround, set the constraints on `TFrame` instances.

Comment: Just tried it and this workaround doesn't work for me, even if I set constraints on panels.

Comment: Of course you need to remove the constraints from the original `TFrame`. The problem is also visible if using `OnConstrainedResize`. Did you already report it to Emb QP?

Comment: Sure I did, It propably workes only on parent without `alClient`. With  `lFrame1` it works, but with `lFrame2` nothing changes.