# Position of controls on panel with bevels

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

For some time now I have been struggling with the strage behavior of controls with `Align` or `Anchors` settings (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201919/resizing-frames-with-width-constraints)). This time I worked with one unit until I noticed that the top position of the buttons moved from the original 10 to something about -50, so I tried to find out what was the cause.

If I use panel with `BevelKind = bkFlat` and controls with `Anchors = [akRight, akBottom]` then the position of all controls will be reduced according to the settings. As shown in the following example, `Left` moves with `Anchors = [akRight]` and `Top` with `Anchors = [akBottom]`. Always in the width of the bevels that the panel has set, in this case -4 in both directions. After running the program or reopening the following unit, position moves from `(150, 10)` to `(146, 6)` and will continue indefinitely after opening and saving the unit.

So I'd like to know what is responsible for position recalculation of all components after opening the unit and saving into `dfm` file, if it is possible to fix it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**PMain.pas**

```
unit PMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Grids;

type
  TUMain = class(TForm)
    pnl1: TPanel;
    btn1: TButton;
  end;

var
  UMain: TUMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

**PMain.dfm**

```
object UMain: TUMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'UMain'
  ClientHeight = 50
  ClientWidth = 250
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object pnl1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 250
    Height = 50
    Align = alClient
    BevelKind = bkFlat
    Caption = 'pnl1'
    TabOrder = 0
    DesignSize = (
      246
      46)
    object btn1: TButton
      Left = 150
      Top = 10
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Anchors = [akRight, akBottom]
      Caption = 'btn1'
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One advice: either use `Align` or use `Anchors`, but don't try both at the same time. `Align` is nice if you want something completely tucked to one side or if you want to cover something entirely. Anchors are nice to keep borders of a control growing or moving with the borders of the parent (in one or more directions), even if things are not at the absolute edges.

Comment: @Rudy I don't think that's what OP is doing. In the DFM, it shows the `TPanel` is aligned `alClient`, while the `TButton` on that panel has anchors `[akRight, akBottom]`. In fact, I do this all the time (anchored button on aligned panel), and have never experienced any issues as OP describes.

Comment: @Jerry You should try example above with `Bevels` and`BevelKind = bkFlat`, I think that's the problem.

Comment: @Triber Yes, I just recreated your problem. After closing and re-opening, the button shifted up / left by 2 pixels in each direction. Definitely a Delphi bug. Not much you can do, other than not use those bevels in design-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Delphi. I recreated the same behavior using your above code in Delphi 10 Seattle.

The only thing you can really do is to not set these particular bevels in design-time. Instead, set that in run-time...

```
pnl1.BevelKind := bkFlat;
```

Chances are, without digging into the controls, is that the order in which the properties are streamed from the DFM is in just the right (or wrong) order to the point where, perhaps, the button gets positioned before the panel is the size it needs to be, for example. I can't imagine a fix you could do without completely re-building the VCL, which is way out of the question.

You should submit a QC report to Embarcadero, if nobody has reported this issue yet.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I will submit report. In my experience, I just don't beleive, they will fix it in near future. One solution how to achieve same effect is to place `pnl1` inside  another `TPanel` with 4 aligned `TBevel` around. It's not ideal, but better than nothing.